# JSON calls object recursively when posting it

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, persistence

I'm testing my app via Swagger and when trying to post an object, which contains a list of other objects, I get an error  java.lang.StackOverflowError. Basically, I'm trying to write an invoice, represented as JSON in Swagger form, and while filling in the data for my invoice I've noticed that invoice item contains the duplicated fields for invoice.

```
{
  "date": "2017-08-27",
  "counterparty": {
    "address": {
      "houseNumber": "string",
      "streetName": "string",
      "townName": "string",
      "zipCode": "string"
    },
    "bankName": "string",
    "bankNumber": "string",
    "companyName": "string",
    "nip": "string",
    "phoneNumber": "string"
  },
  "invoiceItems": [
    {
      "amount": 0,
      "description": "string",
      "id": 0,
      "invoice": { //SHOULD NOT BE HERE
        "id": 0,
        "date": "2017-09-07",
        "counterparty": {
          "address": {
            "houseNumber": "string",
            "streetName": "string",
            "townName": "string",
            "zipCode": "string"
          },
          "bankName": "string",
          "bankNumber": "string",
          "companyName": "string",
          "nip": "string",
          "phoneNumber": "string"
        },
        "invoiceItems": [
          {}
        ]
      },
      "numberOfItems": 0,
      "vat": "VAT_23",
      "vatAmount": 0
    }
  ]
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "invoices")
public class Invoice implements Comparable<Invoice> {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      @Column(name = "invoice_id")
      private int id;
      @Column(name = "date")
      private LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
      @OneToOne(mappedBy = "invoice", cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,
          CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
      private Counterparty counterparty;

      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoice", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
          CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
      private List<InvoiceItem> invoiceItems = new ArrayList<>();

@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class InvoiceItem {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "item_id")
  private int id;
  private String description;
  private int numberOfItems;
  private BigDecimal amount;
  private BigDecimal vatAmount;

  @JoinColumn(name = "vat_code")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
  private Vat vat;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
      CascadeType.REFRESH})
  @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id")
  private Invoice invoice;
```

I have the very same mapping with Counterparty, but it doesn't show me invoice data in JSON:

```
@Id
  private String nip;
  private String companyName;
  private String phoneNumber;
  private String bankName;
  private String bankNumber;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "counterparty", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Address address;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
      CascadeType.REFRESH})
  @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id")
  private Invoice invoice;
```

Maybe there are some issues with my annotations that invoice is being called recursively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mark your Invoice property on InvoiceItems with the @JsonIgnore annotation which means it won't be serialized into JSON when the InvoiceItems is serialized which should prevent your infinitely recursive JSON issue:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "items")
 public class InvoiceItem {

 ...

     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
      CascadeType.REFRESH})
     @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id")
     @JsonIgnore
     private Invoice invoice;
```